# SSH tunnel: Get client ip in remote server

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm tunneling 2 servers:

ServerA & ServerB

with the following command on `ServerA`

```
ssh -NTC -L 0.0.0.0:30238:<ServerB>:30238 user@ServerB
```

The connection establishes successfully.

However, when a client/user is connected to `ServerA`, I don't get the "client/user" IP on `ServerB`. I get `ServerB` ip.

Is there any way I can fix it and get the real client IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a lot, I learned that preserving the client IP after `SSH` tunnel is impossible.

To have client IP, you need to use other approaches for tunneling.